# Different behavior of ArcObjects for different languages

Tags: arcobjects, c#, symbology

I have the same code in C++ and C# for ArcMap. This code loads a document from disk and trying to get a picture for `PictureSimbol` object. But in case of C++ error occurs(`HRESULT = E_UNEXPECTED` 0x8000ffff). C# code works without any problem. Why such a difference may occur? (`mxd_file_name` the same in both cases)

C++ code

```
esriCarto::IMapDocumentPtr map_doc(esriCarto::CLSID_MapDocument);
map_doc->Open(mxd_file_name, L"");
esriCarto::IMapPtr mp = map_doc->Map[0];
esriCarto::IFeatureLayerPtr layer = mp->Layer[0];
esriCarto::ILegendInfoPtr inf = layer;
esriCarto::ILegendGroupPtr gr = inf->GetLegendGroup(0);
esriCarto::ILegendClassPtr cl = gr->Class[0];
esriDisplay::ISymbolPtr s = cl->Symbol;
esriDisplay::IMultiLayerFillSymbolPtr mls = s;
esriDisplay::IFillSymbolPtr fs = mls->Layer[0];
esriDisplay::IPictureFillSymbolPtr pfs = fs;

IPictureDisp * pic = 0;
HRESULT hr = pfs->get_Picture(&pic); // hr = E_UNEXPECTED 0x8000ffff catastrophic failure
map_doc->Close();
```

C#

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMapDocument map_doc = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.MapDocument();
map_doc.Open(mxd_file_name);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMap mp = map_doc.Map[0];
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer layer = mp.Layer[0] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILegendInfo inf = layer as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILegendInfo;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILegendGroup gr = inf.LegendGroup[0];
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILegendClass cl = gr.Class[0];
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISymbol s = cl.Symbol;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IMultiLayerFillSymbol mls = s as ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IMultiLayerFillSymbol;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IFillSymbol fs = mls.Layer[0];
ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IPictureFillSymbol pfs = fs as ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IPictureFillSymbol;
stdole.IPictureDisp pic = pfs.Picture; // works fine
map_doc.Close();
```

---

There is no problem with `IPictureDisp * pic = 0;` Actually I just paste code for `IPictureDispPtr pic = pfs->GetPicture()` because I do not want an exception instead of error `HRESULT`. Bellow is an autogenerated code for `GetPicture` function

```
inline IPictureDisp * IPictureFillSymbol::GetPicture ( ) {
    IPictureDisp * _result = 0;
    HRESULT _hr = get_Picture(&_result);
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _result;
}
```

C++ code works, if the map is not taken from hard drive but obtained from the same document that loaded in ArcMap. Here's the code:

```
esriArcMapUI::IMxDocumentPtr document(application_->Document); // application_ is the ArcMap application
esriCarto::IMapPtr mp = document->Maps->Item[0];
// the rest code is unchanged
esriCarto::IFeatureLayerPtr layer = mp->Layer[0];
esriCarto::ILegendInfoPtr inf = layer;
esriCarto::ILegendGroupPtr gr = inf->GetLegendGroup(0);
esriCarto::ILegendClassPtr cl = gr->Class[0];
esriDisplay::ISymbolPtr s = cl->Symbol;
esriDisplay::IMultiLayerFillSymbolPtr mls = s;
esriDisplay::IFillSymbolPtr fs = mls->Layer[0];
esriDisplay::IPictureFillSymbolPtr pfs = fs;

IPictureDisp * pic = 0;
HRESULT hr = pfs->get_Picture(&pic); // same code works fine
map_doc->Close();
```

Comment: Esri's doc on [smart types](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_cpp/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Smart_types/000100000004000000/) says: "Beware! Don't use the & operator to pass data. Instead, put your smart pointer in a container structure and pass the address of the container structure."

Comment: @Kirk - I expanded my question with pointer stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the c++ code runs in a separate thread and this thread hasn't a `CoInitialize` call. After adding this call (+ `CoUnitialize`) to the thread function the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This line here may be the issue.

```
esriDisplay::IPictureFillSymbolPtr pfs = fs;
```

You're accessing the method:

```
get_Picture(&pic)
```

using pointer notation, but not declaring as a pointer.

try:

```
...
esriDisplay::IPictureFillSymbolPtr *pfs = fs;

IPictureDisp * pic = 0;
HRESULT hr = pfs->get_Picture(&pic);
...
```

Comment: It is not the problem. C++ code works fine, if the map is not taken from hard drive (via `IMapDocument.Open`) but obtained from the same document that loaded in ArcMap (via `IApplication.Document as IMxDocument`)